# Installing Cloudera CDH5 using cloudera manager in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am trying to install CDH5 using Cloudera Manager in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64bit). I was following the steps mentioned in the [Cloudera link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-manager/v4-6-0/Cloudera-Manager-Installation-Guide/cmig_install_path_A.html?scroll=cmig_topic_6_5). I was not able to specify the correct host name for installing the CDH5. I dont have any other entries except for 127.0.0.1 & 127.0.1.1 in the /etc/hosts file.

I am using USB dongle for accessing internet and I dont have any ethernet connection right now. Please let me know whether I need to have an ethernet connection to install CDH5 in my PC.

P.S. I am currently working as a mainframe developer and do not have any linux or open source background. I spent almost 40 hours of time trying to install the CDH5 in my machine so that I can work on the exercises in the [Udacity's Introduction to Hadoop Course](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud617).My PC runs on a Intel Dual core processor which doesn't support the virtualisation to use VMWARE. Hence I got no other options but to install CDH5 in a dual boot partition of ubuntu. Kindly guide me proceeding further.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Windows-7 64-bit, then get VMWare Player installed.
get centOS-6.3 32-bit vmware-image. It will be able to run on your 64-bit Windows.
And from cloudera site, download a cdh5.repo file. Install CDH5 from that repos file...its very simple.